# scrolltop does not work on centos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, centos

I am trying to make scrolling smooth onclick of a button. It works fine with local apache server and IE10+. but when deployed in project on "centos" It doesn’t work on same browser. No error is generated. Can anyone help me finding the reason behind this?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    //+ Scroll smoothly to the target href.
    $("#btnGenerate").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var offset = $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top;
        if (offset == 0)
        {
            offset = 230;
        }

        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: offset
            },
            1000,
            function () {
                alert('animation complete.');
            }
        );
    });
    //-
});
```

HTML:

```
<input id="btnGenerate" href="#labelFirstChart" type="button" value="Generate"/>
```

Comment: What does the browser console say?...Smooth as in what exactly you want?..The code here should work fine..

Comment: on console offset value is good as expected. but animate function dosen't get called.

Comment: still stucked into the problem. anyone have any answer?

Answer (score 0):

This should work with a elements which have an anchor link:

```
$('a[href^=#]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({ 
        scrollTop:$(href).offset().top
    },'slow');
});
```

Here is an example:

http://codepen.io/acki/pen/wMGaPB

Comment: What does the browser console means? Some JS errors?

Comment: Thanks for your help Christoph but it works good on localhost. but on centos dose not. All included jquery and other files are same on both the project.

Comment: If you copy my code into a testfile on CentOS, did it works then?

Comment: And: can you provide me a testlink?

Comment: Yes. tryout works. seems like error in code file. compiled file throughoutly no error.

Comment: Nice. Can you accept my answer please? Thanks and all the best.